# HuggingFace Tokenizer for multiple columns

Tags: multiple-columns, tokenize, huggingface-tokenizers

I have a dataset that has 2 text columns and 1 output column.

```
 text_a               text_b              output
"This is a bird"    "This is a pencil"       0
"This is a cat"     "This is a pen"          1
```

I am reading the data and get input and output columns like following:

```
import pandas as pd
df_train = pd.read_csv("./train.csv")
y_train = list(df_train.pop('output'))
x_train = df_train.values.tolist()
```

Later, use tokenizer and feed it with x_train:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
train_encodings = tokenizer(x_train, truncation=True, padding=True)
```

Here, I used both text_a and text_b columns to feed the tokenizer. But I have seen most of the blogs are using tokenizer for column by column. I am just wondering that if this is also a valid option to converting text to numeric representations.